# Meteor.settings undefined in production

Tags: meteor, dokku

I am deploying to DigitalOcean using Dokku, but for some reason, my all references to Meteor.settings returned undefined

Any idea as to why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Once the app is deployed, to get the settings you need to set the METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable with the JSON for your settings.

```
METEOR_SETTINGS=`cat settings.json` ROOT_URL=... MONGO_URL=... node main.js
```